# Bumping Spring Boot 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 no AuthenticationManager in application context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

When running 2.1.9 the following worked:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChainForActuator(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/actuator/**"))
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/actuator/health")
        .permitAll()
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .hasRole("MONITORING")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .build();
  }
```

After bumping to 2.2.0 all tests trying to create a ApplicationContext fails with the message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityWebFilterChainForActuator' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityWebFilterChainForActuator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityWebFilterChainForActuator' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityWebFilterChainForActuator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:711)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityWebFilterChainForActuator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.<init>(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$HttpBasicSpec.configure(ServerHttpSecurity.java:2931)
    at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity.build(ServerHttpSecurity.java:2349)
    at com.xxx.supportportal.security.SecurityConfig.securityWebFilterChainForActuator(SecurityConfig.java:111)
    at com.xxx.supportportal.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fa16929.CGLIB$securityWebFilterChainForActuator$2(<generated>)
    at com.xxx.supportportal.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fa16929$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$491e366e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at com.xxx.supportportal.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fa16929.securityWebFilterChainForActuator(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 61 more
```

Reading the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes) does not make me any smarter.

Why are my test failing and where is this change documented?

UPDATE: content of POM

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- Done since jacoco needs more memory in build pipe else it crashes -->
    <argLine>-Xms128m -Xmx4096m</argLine>
    <!-- 3rd party dep versions -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium.version>
    <log4j.version>2.11.1</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <awssdk.version>2.9.5</awssdk.version>
    <resilience4j.version>1.1.0</resilience4j.version>
    <access-token-retriever>2</access-token-retriever>
    <mockserver>3.10.0</mockserver>
    <micrometer>1.2.0</micrometer>
    <!-- frontend configuration -->
    <frontendSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontendSrcDir>
    <node.version>v10.15.0</node.version>
    <yarn.version>v1.13.0</yarn.version>
    <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    <isCi>true</isCi>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Security Sonar fixes, insecure libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.64</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>7.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Explicit dependency since sonarcube finds vulnerability -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>${awssdk.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--For sending metrics to aws-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2</artifactId>
        <version>${micrometer}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!---->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- To avoid duplicate JsonObject on classpath -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Resilience4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END -->

    <!-- AWS -->
    <!-- Used to set proxy on the apache http client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Used to be able to assume roles locally -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add service clients below -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cognitoidentityprovider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>ssm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudwatch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--END-->
    <!-- JWT Decode -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Misc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
        <version>${mockserver}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you post your **pom.xml** ?

Comment: the oauth2 dependencies are not needed as this is included into spring security nowdays

Comment: The change that caused your problem is more likely to have originated in Spring Security which was updated to 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did exclude `ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` in my `SpringBootApplication` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

After removing the exclude my tests were green again.